# Python, filtering list based on matched words

Tags: python

What could be the more quicker way to achieve the following ?

```
# Expected Output for original_list 

['Ju Moran', 'Luo Jiangning', 'Wang Zhongbo', 'Luo Haibo']

# Expected Output for rule_filter

['McGill University', 'Oba School', 'Test Case Filter']
```

```py
import re


filter_words = [
    'school',
    'university',
    'branch'
]

original_list = ['Ju Moran', 'Luo Jiangning', 'Wang Zhongbo',
                 'Luo Haibo', 'McGill University', 'Oba School', 'Test Case Filter']

rule_filter = [x for x in original_list if len(re.sub('\S+', '', x)) > 1]

[original_list.remove(i) for i in rule_filter]
```

In a simple manner, am trying to remove elements which have more than one space and matched my `filter_words`

> Previous code already handle the space part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a for loop to read the original list only once, but you need another list to store the result and reassign it back to the original list after the loop. Also, I think `count(" ")` is enough for counting space, no need to use re. As your expected result is case insensitive, `lower()` is used.

```
new_original = []
rule_filter = []
for word in original_list:
    if word.count(" ") > 1 or any(filter_word.lower() in word.lower() for filter_word in filter_words):
        rule_filter.append(word)
    else:
        new_original.append(word)
original_list = new_original

print(original_list) # Output: ['Ju Moran', 'Luo Jiangning', 'Wang Zhongbo', 'Luo Haibo']
print(rule_filter) # Output: ['McGill University', 'Oba School', 'Test Case Filter']
```

List comprehension version will involve two for loop but no extra list needed:

```
rule_filter = [w for w in original_list if w.count(" ") > 1 or any(f.lower() in w.lower() for f in filter_words)]
original_list = [w for w in original_list if w not in rule_filter]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

```py
filter_words = [
    'school',
    'university',
    'branch'
]

original_list = ['Ju Moran', 'Luo Jiangning', 'Wang Zhongbo',
                 'Luo Haibo', 'McGill University', 'Oba School', 'Test Case Filter']

f = [i for i in original_list if all(j.lower() not in i.lower() for j in filter_words)]

print(f)
```

You can remove **.lower()** if you want to be case sensitive and separate the exact words.

Comment: i was looking to append those to `rule_filter ` as well. so i can have list of removed elements and list of final modified list.